# Adding multiple columns and deleting duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-2003

My dad owns a wholesale store and most invoices come via Excel.  The issue is usually it takes a lot of time manually editing the files to sum the columns up (doing it manually).

Currently I'm doing it like this:

Create new row.
Sum(Range) then overwriting it with the value, deleting the originals.

Data:

```
Box Count    UPC       UPC Description        Item Qty   Cost      Ext Cost
    22  07244700571 BARGE BEACH SET                 40   $2.00   $80.00
    12  69420231150 DISCOVERY KIDS BLLN PUMPER      8    $4.00   $32.00 
    73  69420230872 DK MAMMOTH SPRINKLER            75   $4.50   $337.50 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    3   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    3   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    4   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
    4   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
    3   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    4   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          11   $2.54   $27.94 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    1   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    1   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
    1   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
    2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54
```

Is there a way I can have it Sum Col A (Box Count), Col D (Individual Quantity), while only allowing there 1 row entry? (Also bringing down the individual cost Col E.  I can easily do a formula to do extended cost.)

I guess what I'm saying:

For the part that shows:

```
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
3   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
3   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
4   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
4   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
3   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
4   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          11   $2.54   $27.94 
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
1   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
1   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
1   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54 
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          2    $2.54   $5.08 
2   07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE          1    $2.54   $2.54
```

is there a formula or script I can have it automatically combine to say:

```
40  07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE 31  $2.54
```

Comment: Assuming you want to do this (i.e. sum box count and qty) for each product, would a pivot table suffice?

Comment: I've tried Pivot table and it doesn't output correctly..

Comment: I basically need 1 entry (E.g): 07244708019 EST BEACH SET 10 PIECE

But I need it to add all the values in Column A, Also all the values in Column D, but only have one entry of that Sku +Item Description.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

[image: SO19690724 example]

This is in Tabular form and without subtotalling of the fields.

Example in Excel 2007 Compatibility Mode:

[image: SO19690724 second example]

Comment: Yours is coming out so clean and neat and mine regardless of what I check or uncheck is coming out on 2 lines and a couple of the columns are integrated..

I think it's because it's giving me a total of each item instead of a total of all things.

Comment: Ah do you you have to manually remove the field subtotals?  Yeah I did as you said and it's looking a lot better

Comment: If I can figure out how to remove the Field Subtotals I think we're golden.

Comment: Yeah but it didn't clear it, I'm going to start from scratch on the table because I lost UPC.